# why is "publish in facebook" bringing users to blank comments?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-wall

Whenever a user comments something on my pages and chooses the option 'publish in facebook', the comment appears on his facebook wall correctly, but something weird happens when we try to click on the URL that went to his wall: the string that FB concatenated to the original URL takes the user to a page with blank comments, as if he ended up in another URL altogether.

This content is written in Brazilian Portuguese, but the comment box will be in your default language:

- original content:

http://noticias.bol.uol.com.br/ciencia/2011/11/29/falha-de-memoria-acontece-em-qualquer-idade-faca-o-teste.jhtm

- URL published to the user's FB wall:

http://noticias.bol.uol.com.br/ciencia/2011/11/29/falha-de-memoria-acontece-em-qualquer-idade-faca-o-teste.jhtm?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150377691031582_19179277_10150378626321582&ref=notif&notif_t=open_graph_comment#fb_comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the Plugin's `href` parameter is different in the two links. You need to set this parameter your self to have a consistent result.